# XmlHttpRequest.responseText result?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I am new to JavaScript. I need to test the output of `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` on a given URL. What is the simplest way to do it?

```
var url = "http://m.google.com/"; <br>
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); <br>
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true); <br>
document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; <br>
```

`main-content` is a `<div>` tag. The last line of code will replace the contents of the `<div>` tag with output of `xmlHttp.responseText`.

Now, when I open `m.google.com` in my regular browse and select "View Source", what part of the source gets placed within the `<div>` tag. Or let's stay I have to test this code in - where do I write this code?

Actually, I have an Android app that displays this HTML code result in a `WebView`.

Comment: What do you mean *test the output*?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest.responseText.test(/sumfin/i) ?

Comment: Please define your question more.

Comment: Added the update. Please help!

Comment: You're opening the connection, but you're never sending the request. I've updated my answer in response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip your frustrations and employ [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It's an industry standard and almost every employer asks if you have experience with it.

```
$.get({
 url:'url.html',
 data:{},
 success:function(evt){console.log(evt);}
});
```

However, if you want a go a more difficulte route:

```
var url = "http://m.google.com/"; 
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);

 // subscribe to this event before you send your request.
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
   //alert the user that a response now exists in the responseTest property.
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   // And to view in firebug
   console.log('xhr',xmlhttp)
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null)
```

Comment: Thanks jbcurtin, how do I subscribe to that event from java? Would be great if you gave me the equivalent invocation code as well. Sorry but I am totally new to JS.

Comment: No worries mate. When handling an event in javascript ( javascript is not java, there is kind of a huge difference. ) you need to create a function to handle it. In your case xmlhttp.onreadstatechange = function(evt){//code to handle \n}.

Comment: For additional reading, w3schools is awesome. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Get Firefox with Firebug and browse XMLHttpRequest object for responseText member.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I installed Firebug but where do I see the XMLHttpRequest object. Just to be clear - I am accessing m.google.com from my application. I create the XMLHttpRequest object and then use <code> xmlHttpRequest.responseText </code> in MY application. How do I see THAT output?